# Global headings style names

Tags: c#, ms-word

I use Interop.Word to define auto  numbering of Word document according to its headings.

My Word version is not the English version and styles names are in local language.

Therefore, I have to use the local name for headings names and my application does not support both my Word version and English version.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    //  This line is work well as my Word version is not the English version
    lt.ListLevels[i].LinkedStyle ="Heading_Name_In_My_Language " + i;  

    //  This line fails.            
    lt.ListLevels[i].LinkedStyle="Heading " + i;  
}
```

I have tried to use     `WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1.ToString()` 
as the LinkedStyle value, but its value is not "Heading 1", it is "wdStyleHeading1" and even  when I use SubString() method to get the end of that string,
I get the following error: "This name is not a valid style name".

Any Ideas?